# Is it possible to use 3rd party reactjs components with react-native like google maps?

Tags: ios, google-maps, reactjs, react-native

Hi I am new to react native. Is it possible to use 3rd party reactjs components with react-native, google maps?

Answer (score 2):

If the 3rd party reactjs components use `DOM`, you can only use them with browser, like `WebView`. React-"Native" use Native iOS/Android component like `UIView`, not `DOM`.